# IIS 7.5 how to verify if Auto-Start actually works?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, autostart

I hosted my asp.net mvc3 application on amazon ec2 cloud using windows server 2008 R2.  The first time page loading is very slow. I decided to enable auto start on IIS 7.5.

I followed Scott's post.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I only have one web application hosted on this server, and this application got its own app pool, not shared with anything else.

this is all I did, add  startMode="AlwaysRunning".

here's hte problem. I see performance gets a little bit better, but still about 4-5 seconds.

Is there way to verify  if my auto-start setting acutally works?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to IIS Manager on the box, you can examine "Worker Processes" for the site. Otherwise, look for a process named w3wp.exe. If you only have one site, it should be the only process.

Try stopping the application and confirming the worker process has stopped. Now start the application without issuing a request. If the process is there, auto-start is working.

EDIT: Slides 11 and 12 from http://www.slideshare.net/brianritchie1/iis-alwayson-services may be helpful.